# Bare expo app vs React native cli app: what is better?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-cli

I will start building an app that requires native code.
I am hesitating between a bare expo app, or pure react-native cli app.

I already have experience with expo bare workflow and native code.

**Are there advantages to prefere on over the other?**

Also, if I choose expo-bare over react-native cli, will my app be bigger (in terms of build size), less performant, or more battery consuming?